# Classic ASP Access database query, sum and group

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP front end to an Access database (2003) and would like to run some calculations on my data.  I have items that are rented on a daily basis and there is a daily running cost associated with that. Here are the table details;

- Table name: rent_table
- Fields:

  - rentid
  - startdate
  - enddate
  - rentfee
  - rentcost
  - bookingfee

Currently in Excel I do this;

(startdate-enddate) * rentfee+bookingfee  -minus  (startdate-enddate) * rentcost

That gives me the profit per rentid.  I order it by enddate and then group it on a monthly basis (end of month) so that when the enddate has expired I know that the profit can be released. In Excel I manually do the month grouping / summing.

The goal is to automate the process in ASP so that I get the results summarised;

- Report Heading:  profit, monthend
- Result line1:    £2.00, Jan 14
- Result line2:    £4.00, Feb 14
- Result lineN:    £6.00, Jan 16

I know how to construct the ASP page, connect to the database and display query results.  It is really the query that I need please. Thank you in advance (and please be gentle, my first post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should get you close.  The query is untested but should give you a good starting point.  The month will be returned as a number from 1 to 12; you will probably want to format that as you see fit.

```
SELECT Month(enddate) AS Mo, Year(enddate) as Yr, 
       Sum( ((enddate - startdate) * rentfee) + bookingfee - ((enddate - startdate) * rentcost) ) as Profit
FROM rent_table
WHERE enddate Is Not Null
GROUP BY Year(enddate), Month(enddate)
ORDER BY Year(enddate), Month(enddate)
```

Comment: That worked great thank you!  I needed to add CDate in front of the endate/startdate in the Sum as I found out they were text fields in the database (and I didn't want to disturb the db).  Also I added a Round(...,2) to the Sum in order to trim off any excess decimals. Lastly I converted the month number to a month name using an IF statement. Job done.